# How do I force a background image to appear when printing for the first time in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing

When the page is refreshed or first opened in Chrome; When you want to print, the background image disappears. How do I make the print background appear permanently

If print with Şablonlu is selected, it adds a picture to the background. Otherwise, it does not.
[image]

```
       <div id="test" class="visible-print"></div>
            @if (isFiligran == true)
            {
                <script>
                    $("#test").addClass("backgroundd")
                </script>
            }


.backgroundd {
        /*background-color:#ccc;*/
        background-image: url('../../../../Content/Image/selcuklu-yildizi.jpg') !important;
        position: fixed !important;
        bottom: 0 !important;
        top: 0 !important;
        height: 100%!important;
        width: 100%!important;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
        visibility:visible;

    }
    .backgroundtransparent{
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9) !important;
        position:fixed !important;
        background-size:contain !important;
        top:72px !important;
        height:calc(100% - 144px)!important;
        width: 101%!important;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
        visibility:visible;
        
    }

@media print {
.backgroundtransparent {
                display: block !important;
                -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
            }
            .backgroundd {
                display: block !important;
                -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
            
            }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Some (if not all) browsers do not print backgrounds by default. You have to alter a setting within the browser.

Comment: What settings do I need to change in the browser?

Comment: Depends on the browser. Have a look at settings and see what is associated with printing.

Comment: It is selected as follows in the browser settings, but it still does not appear at the first time

Comment: In view of the info in your recent answer(which please move to enhance your question as it hasn’t fully solved the problem) I think we need a runnable snippet which demonstrates the image not showing first time, and a description of what that means.

Comment: I added more details to my question. Now the css properties are like this but it doesn't show in the first time

Comment: Please explain (in  English) what 'print with Şablonlu' means, thanks. (I looked it up but couldn't make it match a printing term).

Comment: "Şablonlu" means add background? It adds an image to the background when the Selected Şablonlu type is selected on the application. I am adding my question